# Invoke event of one form from another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

On my `MDIform` click event I am opening my `Form2` by passing my control and one event like this:

```
Form2 Obj = new Form2(ListBox1, ListBox1_ItemChanged);
```

And my From2 has opening class declared like this:

```
private readonly ListBox m_AssigndTree;
private EventHandler navChange;
public Form2(ListBox1 AssigndTree, EventHandler ListBox1_ItemChanged)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    m_AssigndTree = AssigndTree;
    navChange = NavBarGroup3_ItemChanged;
}
```

Now have a click event on `Form2` and I want to fire the event `ListBox1_ItemChanged` How I can do that, as to invoke the event of same form I use to do directly `myEvent.Invoke += (parameters)`

I have the following event on `Form2`:

```
private void button1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // navChange.Invoke += 
}
```

Comment: use event handler see this : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/db5ccada-2eef-4803-90a4-10609abbe13a/how-to-fire-event-in-other-form

Comment: Where could you find the `ItemChanged` event of a `winforms ListBox`?

Comment: @KingKing Actually its an userDefined control

Comment: @DjangoAnonymous: how `frm_list_patients` is related to `Form2`?

Comment: @Dennis It was by mistake: Its `Form2` only. Thanks pointing out, I have done the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't raise an event, declared in another type, directly.
`ListBox1_ItemChanged` in your sample is just an instance of `EventHandler` delegate, this is **not** and event.

Answer (score -1):

To call an event use it like a function:

```
m_AssigndTree.ItemChanged();
```

You'll need to make up the arguments